# Draggable line serie

Tags: jqplot

I have draggable line serie on my chart. Is there any way to allow set only integer values when dragging? Some kind of snap or constraint only to integer numbers.

Comment: Can you provide some code, or perhaps a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: For example http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/customHighlighterCursorTrendline.html

Comment: @TOUDIdel Any progress on this one? Did you managed to make it yourself?

Comment: @Boro: No, I didn't. Only one thing I did is rounding (to integer) values during reading values from chart to data table.